# SSL Exception From Sql server while trying to connect from Java 1.6, JDBC 4.0

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I am getting the following issue repeatedly. There is no use of SSL for authentication, I have Java 1.6, and JDBC 4.0 placed with Spring 3.2. This is an 
Spring Batch application, the exception is not stopping the scheduler jobs but it is causing issue during database operations.

Please help me to find the root cause of this issue.

```
2019/08/08 19:55:38,223 INFO   - JobExecutionListener in before JOB NOT RUNNING10077830 7 
    Aug 8, 2019 7:55:38 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
    INFO: java.security path: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/security
    Security providers: [SunPKCS11-Solaris version 1.6, SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC version 1.6]
    SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
    SSLContext provider services:
    [SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
    , SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
      aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
    , SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignature
    , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
    , SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
    , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
    , SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
      aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
    , SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl
    , SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
    ]
    java.ext.dirs: /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/ext:/usr/jdk/packages/lib/ext
    2019/08/08 19:55:38,264 ERROR  - Encountered fatal error executing job 
    org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
            at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
            at com.cbkonnect.h2h.batch.quartz.JobLauncherDetails.executeInternal(JobLauncherDetails.java:51)
            at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:113)
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
    Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=FILE_RECIEVE_ACK at state=FILE_RECIEVE_ACK.FILE_RECIEVE_ACK_STEP1 with exception
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:161)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:0b74d397-671c-44fb-9c9e-18f6b2e6fbb6".
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:241)
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
            at $Proxy14.getStepExecutionCount(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.isStepRestart(JobFlowExecutor.java:82)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:63)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
            at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
            ... 10 more
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:0b74d397-671c-44fb-9c9e-18f6b2e6fbb6".
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
            at com.cbkonnect.jdbc.datasource.CbkonnectDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(CbkonnectDataSource.java:210)
            at com.cbkonnect.jdbc.datasource.CbkonnectDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(CbkonnectDataSource.java:182)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:203)
            ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:0b74d397-671c-44fb-9c9e-18f6b2e6fbb6
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
            at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
            ... 32 more
    2019/08/08 19:55:38,277 INFO   - JobExecutionListener after JOB
```

Comment: _"There is no use of SSL for authentication"_, SQL Server JDBC uses SSL by default. The problem is probably with SSL/TLS support in Java 6 and you may need to upgrade to a newer Java version to fix this.

Comment: fixed by Upgrading to Java 8 and JDBC 4.2.

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem when using JDK6? We cannot upgrade to JAv 8 and setting the property -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1 has no effect since this property is only available in later JDK versions